# How to combine dataframes with different column numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 data frames like below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyAgq.png)
df_date and df1 and df2
df1 and df2 have the same columns A B C D

i want to combine it like below in one data frame like below: and the dataframe should have dupplication in date and the same columns A B C D
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVFQ7.png)